# Network Scenario - Configuration and Suggestions

Tags: networking, vpn, home-networking

I have the following scenario:

```
My Computer (Linux) --> INTERNET --> Remote Computer (Windows - NO PUBLIC IP) in LAN with IP Address 192.168.1.130 --> Another LAN (I have another ETH card attached to the remote computer) --> Device (Linux) with IP 10.1.1.5 (where currently I'm connecting in SSH/SFTP).
```

How can I connect directly to the Device starting from My Computer? Which tools and protocols may I use?

At the moment I'm using Teamviewer, but it is a mess every time that I need to upload/download something from the Device.

I tried with Hamachi on the remote computer, but I'm not able to ping the device. Do you have any suggestion?